Authentication Error when Connecting to Neo4j using Python Script
I'm encountering an authentication error when trying to connect to my Neo4j database using a Python script. Despite providing the correct credentials, I receive an Unauthorized error. Here are the details of my setup and the steps I've taken so far:
Environment:

Neo4j Version: 4.0 (Community Edition)
Python Version: 3.12
Neo4j Python Driver Version: 4.4

Problem Description:
I am trying to create nodes and relationships in my Neo4j database using a Python script. However, I keep getting an authentication error when attempting to connect. Here is the exact error message:

neo4j.exceptions.AuthError: {code: Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized} {message: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.}

Could anyone help me understand why my authentication attempts are failing from the Python script but succeeding from the browser? Are there any additional steps I should take to troubleshoot this issue?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

In particular, add to your question the code that attempts to provide the credentials.

Maybe this helps: It seems that there is a default set up for Neo4j which is controlled by the neo4j server (directly from the terminal). It uses the the auth one provide initially.
But when a project is started via the Neo4j desktop application (eg Movie DBMS example project) it overrides the conf setting (so port might change) and the example DB has its OWN password. Look for the "details" tab in the Movie DBMS (or your example project) and at the bottom you can reset the password. When I did this I was able to access the DB via the langchain driver.

This answer is correct (and so surprising!), as of Dec 2024, and not just for Python, but for all drivers - I used JavaScript/TypeScript's neo4j-driver. On Neo4j Desktop (macOS), I created a new project, importing the sample recommendations project. When prompted, I entered a password and started the database. That same password failed using the neo4j.auth.basic provided by the driver. I reset DBMS password in Details to the same password initially entered, and the driver now successfully connects. What a headache - bravo, @Pet222 !
